# Where can Content-Security-Policy be configured?

Tags: javascript, php, apache, content-security-policy, facebook-pixel

For a customer I am implementing Facebook Pixel on their website, to allow them to collect marketing statistics. The Facebook Pixel is implemented with the following Javascript, in the `<head>` tag:

```
<script>
  !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
    {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
    n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
    if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
    n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
    t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
    document,'script',
    'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
    fbq('init', '*****************');
    fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
<noscript>
  <img height="1" width="1" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=***************&ev=PageView&noscript=1" />
</noscript>
```

As you see, the script is calling a Javascript file on the `connect.facebook.net` domain. When the code is uploaded to the Production server, I get the following error in Chrome console, due to violation of the `Content-Security-Policy` directive:

```
Refused to load the script 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' platform.twitter.com s3.amazonaws.com cdn.ckeditor.com cdn.syndication.twimg.com www.google-analytics.com ajax.googleapis.com player.vimeo.com".
```

I have gone through the source code for the website (which is built in PHP), and the `Content-Security-Policy` directive isn't configured anywhere there. Nor is it in the `.htaccess` file. Although I am not quite sure, if this *can* be done in the `.htaccess` file.

**Edit:** (added image of response headers)
[image: Response headers]

As seen in the error message as well as in the screenshot above, there *is* a `Content-Security-Policy` directive defined somewhere and I need to find it, so I can whitelist the Facebook domain there. I am thinking, this might have been done on server level in the `httpd.conf`, file which I have no access to, since the website is hosted by an external hosting provider.

So my question is: *Where* can the `Content-Security-Policy` directive be configured if not in PHP code, a html `<meta http-equiv>` attribute or in the `httpd.conf` file? Can this be done else where?

Comment: Is Content-Security-Policy in the response headers?

Comment: If it's not in the HTML somewhere as a meta tag, it would have to be in the Apache configs, either in httpd.conf, or any of the vhost configs. I would grep through all the configs in the apache directory to be sure. If it's not there, is there a frontend server between apache and the browser? They might be adding the header.

Comment: @jburtondev Yes the CSP header is present among the response headers as seen in the screenshot I have added.

AfroThundr: CSP is not in the HTML which leads me to think it must be set on server level. Thank you for reminding me of the vhost configs.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, these are the only places a Content Security Policy may be set:

1. Meta Tags (not the case in your example as that's a header)
2. Apache configuration, ether apache2.conf/httpd.conf or one of the vhost/config files that are concatenated into the main file. Check Sites Available if you can
3. .htaccess, which I would guess is the case here if you can't access the apache config directly.
4. PHP's [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function if headers are being created manually.